# getting domain user name without windows prompt using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net c# site that I have setup in IIS 7.

In IIS I have enabled basic and windows authentication so I can get the domain users username, so if there is a way to get this without prompting that'd be a perfect solution for me.

I am using the follwing statement to get username:

```
String username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
lblUserName.Text = "Welcome" + username;
```

I want to avoid windows prompting for login credentials.

Can you please give me suggestions how can i do this?

Comment: You can use LoginName control

Comment: This also depends on browser. IE passes credentials through, but FireFox for example needs this enabled in FireFox's config before it will pass windows credentials through.

Comment: This is a typical case of information disclosure, why would I want my browser to tell everything my internal network setup (domain details) without asking me first? IE does this for sites in the intranet zone only, everything else requires a login prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way the server can know the visiting user's name is if that user authenticates using their Windows credentials. By default, IE and Chrome will do so without a prompt *if and only if* the site in question is located in the **Intranet** security zone. Otherwise, the login prompt is shown to prevent the information disclosure threat that Simon mentions.